# Android GPS Tracking issue

Tags: java, android, gps

I tried to get a location for my android app but `getLastKnownLocation` always returns `null` and `onLocationChanged` is never called. I use the following permissions for my app:

```
ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, 
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.
```

GPS and internet are turned on, on my device on. Also I tried different values for `requestLocationUpdates`.

```
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) 
        {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } 
        else 
        {
            hasGPS      = true;
            location    = null;
            if (isGPSEnabled) 
            {
                if (location == null) 
                {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    if (locationManager != null) 
                    {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) 
                        {
                            lat = location.getLatitude();
                            lng = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (isNetworkEnabled && location == null) 
            {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                if (locationManager != null) 
                {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) 
                    {
                        lat = location.getLatitude();
                        lng = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This may sounds silly, but you're testing this on an actual handset correct (ie, not using the emulator)?

Comment: Relateds that may help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621882/getlastknownlocation-returning-null) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608632/android-locationmanager-getlastknownlocation-returns-null).

Comment: yes i tried this code on a tablet with android 4.1

Comment: Install a well-known Android app where you can see whether GPS is functional. BTW where is your listener for the location updates?

Answer (score 0):

GetLastKnownLocation will return null if it either never has had a location via that provider or if the location is too old.  So that isn't unexpected.  Most likely you aren't getting a GPS signal, which can take several seconds-several minutes (or fail altogether in a lot of buildings).  Double check that GPS is turned on in settings, and look at the flashing circle in the notification area-  if it never becomes solid, then you aren't getting a signal.

Comment: Thanks for this hint, the circle never becomes solid. I will try it now  outside.

Answer (score 0):

GPS signal cannot penetrate through walls, so it usually does not work inside buildings.

For developing and testing purposes you can use Android mock locations:
http://developer.android.com/training/location/location-testing.html